# How would i make these dynamic elements reusable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating elements on button click with texts as value and id as key that are store in the localstorage, and i want to recreate them on refresh or another visit. To do that i need to create another same codeblock with little differences.. I'm worried that i can simplify this but i can't think of how to do that, i was about to use clone() on createSet function but the problem is there won't be a default element to clone on the page.

```
ReminderSet.prototype.loadSet = function() {
    var keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = 0,
        key,
        array;

    for (; key = keys[i]; i++) {
        const setId = localStorage.getItem(key);
        array = JSON.parse(setId); //parse and store key values
        let array_index = 0;
        //Re-create the reminders and set their properties//
        $reminderSection.append($('<div/>').addClass('set').attr('id', key) //Set the ID                      
            .append($('<div/>').addClass('set-title').append($('<h1>').attr('contenteditable', 'true').text(array[array_index].set_title)), //Index is always at 0//
                $('<div/>').addClass('create-reminder-control').append($('<button>').addClass('add-new-reminder').text("+ add new"), $('<input>').addClass('create-reminder-value').attr({ type: "text", placeholder: "get something done" })), $('<div/>').addClass('reminder-lists'), $('<div/>').addClass('save-control').append($('<button>').addClass('save-reminder-button').text('Save'))))

        //Get our key values //
        for (; array_index < array.length; array_index++) {
            /*Select the element id */
            $("#" + key).children('.reminder-lists').append($('<div/>').addClass('a-reminder').attr('contenteditable', 'true').text(array[array_index].description)) //Get the reminders
        } //end

    }
};

ReminderSet.prototype.createSet = function(id) {
    id = document.getElementsByClassName('set').length;
    id += 1;
    $reminderSection.append($('<div/>').addClass('set').attr('id', id)
        .append($('<div/>').addClass('set-title').append($('<h1>').attr('contenteditable', 'true').text('Reminders')),
            $('<div/>').addClass('create-reminder-control').append($('<button>').addClass('add-new-reminder').text("+ add new"), $('<input>').addClass('create-reminder-value').attr({ type: "text", placeholder: "get something done" })), $('<div/>').addClass('reminder-lists'), $('<div/>').addClass('save-control').append($('<button>').addClass('save-reminder-button').text('Save'))));
};
$('#create-set').click($.proxy(ReminderSet.prototype.createSet, ReminderSet));

var Reminder = function(description, set_title) {
    this.description = description;
    this.set_title = set_title;
    //Describes the reminder
};

ReminderSet.prototype.loadSet();
```

Comment: What is the current value of `localStorage` key?

Comment: @guest271314 it's an int

Comment: You can store the `.outerHTML` of the elements at `localStorage`, i that is the actual requirement